# Media queries to target high resolution dense pixel devices

Tags: android, css, media-queries

We're trying to target the Samsung Galaxy Nexus specifically. It has a resolution of 1280 x 720 with a pixel density of 2, which causes it to display pages as though it were a desktop device.

We've tried

`@media screen and (max-device-width : 720px) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (portrait) {};`

and

`@media screen and (max-device-width : 720px) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {};`

as well as a variety of other combinations. We can't seem to target this device specifically without effecting either the desktop, tablet or other phone layouts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your media queries are incorrect:

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 720px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
and (orientation : portrait) { /* styles */ };

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 720px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) { /* styles */ };
```

Not sure what you're trying to target with the second one. You may want to consider adding the following media query:

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 1280px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
and (orientation : landscape) { /* styles */ };
```

Try that out.

Comment: was I just missing the "only" before screen?

Comment: That and `orientation :` before `portrait`.

Comment: `@media only screen and (max-device-width : 720px) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation : portrait) {}` is also applying to other phones (iPhone, HTC incredible, etc.)

Comment: Ugh ... Change it to `min-device-width`.

Comment: And that will target iPad 3, as well. Not what you're looking for, I suppose. Well, actually, not in landscape mode. Portrait for iPad 3 is 768px. May have to do some more digging.

Comment: Yeah, that one effected all versions of the ipad which is odd since we're targeting high pixel density devices.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`. `-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio` will target all pixel ratios BELOW 2.

Comment: It no longer targeted the other browsers. However, it didn't work on the Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Was this ever answered? I'm having the same issue with the Samsung Galaxy note

Comment: It wasn't. Dealing with retina displays is rather new and since their resolutions are similar to that of desktops it's difficult to target it specifically. I'll ponder on it some more.