# Css issue with android tablet landscape and desktop screen resolution

Tags: android, css, media-queries

I am trying to write a media query for andriod tablet in landscape mode.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 800px) and (max-device-width
    : 1280px) and (orientation : landscape) {}
```

But here in tablet it is working fine If I am changing my desktop/Laptop resolution to 1280x720px then it is taking the android tablet styles which shouldn't be the case.

Can any one help me out how to overcome with this issue.

Comment: Refer this link For Android Resolutions.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675084/media-queries-to-target-high-resolution-dense-pixel-devices

Comment: @archna Hai I tried adding that it is also not working.. From desktop it is removing but in tablet my styles are not effecting.

Answer (score 0):

for landscape mode you can use max-device-width : 1025px and

for destop you can target

@media screen and (min-device-width: 1281px) {}

Comment: But android support the resolution of 1280px.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```